# Post Build event for renaming / making an extra copy of a file with Fake with f#

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I want to include a post Build event that we have in VS with fake.
As i am pretty new to this i am not sure how to do the same in fake with F#.

Why i need this as i have an External Dll/ Actually an EXCELDNA.XLL that need an config file so i want to rename my default configFile (App.config) with MYDNA.Xll.config .

I also need to make an extra copy of the same config file for the supporting GUI executable ie MyGUIApp.config.

Obviously i don't want to create two config files in project & maintaining the same with every changes.

Answer (score 3):

FAKE has support for "FinalTargets" and BuildFailureTargets. See http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/specifictargets.html

Comment: Thanks forki23 i want to use Copy with relative path of the buildFolder but CopyFile  is failing to do so, giving illegal character path.